# How do I prevent a C# method from executing using an attribute validator?

Tags: c#, validation, attributes

I'd like to create an attribute-based validator that goes a few steps beyond what I've seen in examples. It'll basically prevent methods or other functionality from executing.

Please be aware that I'm having to use [AzMan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998336.aspx) since I have no availability to Active Directory in this scenario.

Here's some pseudo code of what what I'm looking for:

```
// Attribute validator class AttributeUsage is arbitrary at this point and may include other items
[AttributeUsage( AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true )]
public class PermissionsValidatorAttribute : Attribute
{
 public PermissionsValidatorAttribute(PermissionEnumeration permission){...}
 public bool UserCanCreateAndEdit(){...}
 public bool UserCanDelete(){...}
 public bool UserCanUpload(){...}
}
```

Here's a sample of a class/member that'll be decorated. The method will not be executed at all if the PermissionValidator.UserCanDelete() doesn't return true from wherever it's executed:

```
public class DoStuffNeedingPermissions
{
 [PermissionValidator(PermissionEnumeration.MustHaveDeletePermission)]
 public void DeleteSomething(){...}
}
```

I know this is a simple, incomplete example. But you should get the gist of what I'm needing. Make the assumption that DeleteSomething() already exists and I'm preferring to NOT modify the code within the method at all.

I'm currently looking at things like the Validation Application Block and am messing with custom attribute POC's. But I'd love to hear opinions with code samples from everyone out there. I'm also certainly not opposed to other methods of accomplishing the same thing such as extension methods or whatever may work to accomplish the same thing. Please remember I'm making the attempt to minimize changes to existing DoStuffNeedingPermissions code. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Have you considered using Role Based security instead? The user, for example, could be in multiple roles such as CanDelete, CanUpload. DeleteSomething() could check to see if the user is in the appropriate role.

Comment: I'm actually using AzMan for what you're suggesting. But I still have to implement it in the least-intrusive method possible. I'm attempting to keep developers from having to be concerned in their DeleteSomething() type methods. I'm looking for something a little more "automagic".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there a reason you aren't considering the [PrincipalPermissionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.principalpermissionattribute.aspx)?

```
[PrincipalPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name="Bob",
Role="Supervisor")]
```

Comment: My apologies, but I failed to mention I'm having to use AzMan in this scenario. I just edited the details to reflect this.

Comment: Shouldn't matter as this will inspect the current principal in order to determine the permissions. As long as the principal is being setup correctly you should be golden.

Comment: Care to tell anyways how to do such thing? Went through the first 20 google results couldn't find anything, just people recommending already existing tools.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key is not to change `DoStuffNeedingPermissions.`  You would have to modify everything that calls that class' methods to have them check for the permissions.  This is obviously intrusive.  If I *had* to use attributes, I would look at using an AOP framework's intercept capabilities in order to wrap the execution call, and check it there.  This works because security is an archetypal case of cross cutting concerns.